# Move all files which have same names from subdirectories into one directory

Tags: command-line

I am trying to move all files in multiply nested directories into one directory. There are a few posts on this same topic which I followed. The command I used was this:

```
find ./train/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t ./newTrain
```

where train is the folder with the already existing files, and newTrain is the one I want to copy to. The command "somewhat" worked. The problem I have is that  many of the files (and there are A LOT of them) have the exact same name. What seems to have happened is that the first file with a given name moved, then all subsequent files with the same name did not move. Here is a sample output from my command line:

```
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000030.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0080/01-04-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-37331/501-T2WTSEAX-47262/000030.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000031.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0080/01-04-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-37331/501-T2WTSEAX-47262/000031.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000000.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000000.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000001.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000001.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000002.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000002.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000003.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000003.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000004.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000004.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000005.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000005.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000006.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000006.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000007.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000007.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000008.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000008.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000009.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000009.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000010.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000010.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000011.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000011.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000012.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000012.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000013.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000013.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000014.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000014.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000015.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000015.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000016.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000016.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000017.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000017.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000018.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000018.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000019.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000019.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000020.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000020.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000021.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000021.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000022.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000022.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000023.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000023.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000024.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000024.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000025.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000025.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000026.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000026.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000027.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000027.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000028.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000028.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000029.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000029.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000030.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000030.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000031.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000031.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000030.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0080/01-04-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-37331/501-T2WTSEAX-47262/000030.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000031.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0080/01-04-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-37331/501-T2WTSEAX-47262/000031.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000000.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000000.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000001.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000001.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000002.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000002.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000003.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000003.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000004.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000004.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000005.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000005.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000006.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000006.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000007.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000007.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000008.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000008.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000009.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000009.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000010.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000010.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000011.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000011.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000012.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000012.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000013.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000013.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000014.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000014.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000015.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000015.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000016.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000016.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000017.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000017.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000018.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000018.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000019.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000019.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000020.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000020.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000021.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000021.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000022.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000022.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000023.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000023.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000024.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000024.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000025.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000025.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000026.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000026.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000027.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000027.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000028.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000028.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000029.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000029.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000030.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000030.dcm'
mv: will not overwrite just-created './newTrain/000031.dcm' with './train/PROSTATE-DIAGNOSIS/ProstateDx-01-0082/02-09-2010-MRI PROSTATE WITH AND WITHOUT CONTRAST-62402/501-T2WTSEAX-04339/000031.dcm'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Filenames have to be unique for same directory, you would need extra code to check if file already exists and apply some sort of extention to the filename

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell `mv` to make a backup copy if there is already a file in the target directory of the same name:

```
find ./train/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv --backup=numbered -t ./newTrain
```

#### Example

Let's start with a directory `train` that has three files all called `file1`:

```
$ find train
train
train/dir3
train/dir3/file1
train/dir1
train/dir1/file1
train/dir2
train/dir2/file1
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ find ./train/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv --backup=numbered -t ./newTrain
```

We can see that all three files were moved with their names modified as needed to maintain uniqueness:

```
$ find newTrain
newTrain
newTrain/file1.~2~
newTrain/file1
newTrain/file1.~1~
```

#### Improvement

It is not necessary to create a pipeline and use `xargs`.  A simpler version of the command is:

```
find ./train/ -type f -exec mv --backup=numbered -t ./newTrain {} +
```